# Templates and name lookup with `stdio.h` functions

Tags: c++, templates, mingw, fseek, name-lookup

I'm trying to build the `PCL` library in a 32 bit Windows 7 with `MinGW`. When building the [outofcore](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/outofcore) module I got several error messages about `_fseeki64`:

```
error: there are no arguments to '_fseeki64' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_fseeki64' must be available
```

In the `octree_disk_container.h` file, there is a

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define _fseeki64 fseeko
#endif
```

I have tested(generating an `#error`) and `WIN32` is defined at the moment of processing the file. `_fseeki64` seems to be available for the compiler as this little test program compiles:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  FILE* f = fopen("C:/a.txt","r");
  if(!f) printf("NOPE");
  int seekret = _fseeki64(f,4,SEEK_SET);
  (void)seekret;
  return 0;
}
```

If I define `_fseeki64` as `fseeko64` the errors disappear and the module compiles, but I'm not sure if the behaviour will be the same with `fseeko` as was intended to be with `fseeki`.

So, what can I do in order to use `_fseeki64` in this context? Maybe declaring a new base class, putting the `#define` in there and then calling it like `Base<T>::_fseeki64`? (got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277100/1259884))

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems to be that your MinGW system does `#define WIN32`, yet `_fseeki64` is a Microsoft-ism, not a POSIX thing that MinGW knows about.  I think you should use the POSIX behavior on MinGW, which means using `fseeko`.

Comment: Using `fseeko` yields a new error, as `fseeko` is unrecognized. I grepped through the `MinGW` dir and it resulted that only `fseeko64` and `__mingw_fseeko64` are defined. I suppose that `fseeko64` is the right choice, isn't it?